# How can i pass --headers in stripe CLI?

Tags: stripe-payments

When I pass webhook local url

```
stripe listen --forward-to http://localhost:50501/api/Campaign/webhook
```

> Ready! Your webhook signing secret is #############

How to pass headers with --forward-to or in any other way to pass headers with my webhook URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Stripe CLI `listen` command has a [`--headers` option](https://stripe.com/docs/cli/listen#listen-headers) you can use to pass a list of custom headers.

`stripe listen --headers "Foo-header:Bar-value","fizz-header:buzz-value" --forward-to localhost:3000/webhook`

Can you say more about what you're trying to do? Can you provide an example?